# Online Dynamics CRM 2015 web service call error IdentityProvider cannot be null

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I've just started on CRM and ran into some trouble with calling the Organization service. 
I've read that for online CRM that I need to get the device ID and password and pass that in the method.  This is done by calling the HelperCode in the SDK "DeviceIdManager".

All I wanted to do was simply connect to the service and then I'd do what I needed to do (e.g. retrieve account information).

To keep it simple I did (not real username and password):

```
  Uri orgUri = new Uri("https://xxx.api.crm.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc");

  ClientCredentials cc = new ClientCredentials();
  cc.UserName.UserName = "abc123@xxx.onmicrosoft.com";
  cc.UserName.Password = "abc123";

  //GetDeviceCredentials is from the SDK helper class
  OrganizationServiceProxy orgProxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(orgUri, null, cc, GetDeviceCredentials());
  orgProxy.Authenticate();
```

This is the error on the Authenticate():

[image]

I searched around and it seems that I've followed the general idea of what others have done.

Any suggestions on how I can get it to authenticate properly so i can query the account entity would be great.

I've done something similar using the Discover Service and that works (without the Device Credentials) so I'm a bit perplexed of what I've done wrong here.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like a brick.

I should have paid more attention to the MSDN.

The call should have been "LoadOrRegisterDevice" instead of GetDeviceCredentials.